# Case Expression Help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

```html
DECLARE @ServDate DATE = '01/04/2013',
        @PaidDate DATE = '01/25/2013' 

SELECT @ServDate AS DATE ,@PaidDate AS PaidDate ,
       CASE WHEN (MONTH(@ServDate) IN (9,10,11) AND MONTH(@PaidDate) IN (9,10,11) 
            AND YEAR(@ServDate) = YEAR(@PaidDate)) AND (convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate)) 
            = convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@PaidDate))) 
       THEN 'FSY' + ''+ convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate) + 1) + '-' + 'Q1'
 
       WHEN (MONTH(@ServDate) IN (12,1,2) AND MONTH(@PaidDate) IN (12,1,2) AND 
            YEAR(@ServDate) = YEAR(@PaidDate)) AND ( (convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate) + 1)
            = convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@PaidDate))) OR (convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate)) 
            = convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@PaidDate))) ) 
       THEN 'FSY' + ''+
           CASE WHEN (MONTH(@ServDate) IN (1,2) AND MONTH(@PaidDate) IN (1,2)) AND 
                     (convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate)) = convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@PaidDate))) 
           THEN convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate) - 0) + '-' + 'Q2' 
           ELSE convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate) + 1) + '-' + 'Q2' 
           END

       WHEN (MONTH(@ServDate) IN (3,4,5) AND MONTH(@PaidDate) IN (3,4,5) AND 
             YEAR(@ServDate) = YEAR(@PaidDate)) AND (convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate)) 
             = convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@PaidDate))) 
       THEN 'FSY' + ''+ convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate) - 0)+ ' - '+ 'Q3'

       WHEN (MONTH(@ServDate) IN (6,7,8) AND MONTH(@PaidDate) IN (6,7,8) AND 
             YEAR(@ServDate) = YEAR(@PaidDate)) AND (convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate)) 
             = convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@PaidDate))) 
       THEN 'FSY' + ''+ convert(CHAR(4), YEAR(@ServDate) - 0) + ' - ' + 'Q4' 
       ELSE 'NQ' 
       END AS Quarter
```

I have to write a case expression to determine which quarter date belongs too.

Our company Quarter starts Q1: ServDate=9/01/2014 & 11/30/2014  Piad Date 9/1/2014 & 11/30/2014 Will be FSY2015Q1

Quarter will be populated as follows:

```
Q1 - DOS 9/1 to 11/30
Q1 - Paid 9/1 to 11/30
Q2 - DOS 9/1 to 2/28
Q2 - Paid 9/1 to 2/28
Q3 - DOS 9/1 to 5/31
Q3 - Paid 9/1 to 5/31
Q4 - DOS 9/1 to 8/31
Q4 - Paid 9/1 to 8/31
```

So let's say ItemID 1 Servdate 9/01/2014 Paid Date 11/30/2014 will be FSY2015Q1

But If I have a record so let's say ItemID 1 Servdate 9/01/2014 Paid Date 12/30/2014 I need it to say 'NQ' that's where I`m failing....

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not quite clear what you are asking. Take a look at [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select choose(month(date), 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q3, 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q1')
```

`month()` returns the month.  This just looks up the quarter value, which I think starts with Q2 for January.

NOTE:  `choose()` is available in SQL Server 2012+.  You can do the same thing with a `case` statement in earlier versions:

```
select (case month(date) when 1 then 'Q2'
                         when 2 then 'Q2'
         . . .
         end) as quarter
```

Comment: More Like this. Q1 starts in 09/01 till 11/30select (month(getdate ()) ) 'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q1'

Answer (score 0):

Just offset the date by an appropriate number of months. The heart of your requirement is this expression:

```
'Q' + cast(datepart(qq, dateadd(mm, -4, <DATE>)) as char(1))
```

To get the exact text you're looking for just use the quarter number to drive a case expression. The date components could also be calculated but I have a feeling it's not really worth the trouble over hardcoding:

```
case datepart(qq, dateadd(mm, -4, <DATE>)
    when 1 then 'Q1 ...'
    when 2 then 'Q2 ...'
    when 3 then 'Q3 ...'
    when 4 then 'Q4 ...'
end
```